# Retrofit configuration to send a GET request login example

Tags: android, api, rest, authentication, retrofit2

Im very noob at android. Im makin an android aplication with API Rest as well.

I know my back its working, i checked with postman and sends ma request get good:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/{email}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getLogin(HttpServletRequest request,
                @PathVariable(value="email") String email, 
                @PathVariable(value="password") String pass) {
        
        
        System.out.println("Peticion de login recibida");   
        Usuario user = usuarioService.login(email, pass);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But now im trying to configurate my front with Android Studio. I made :
**ApiClient.java**

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static final String API_BASE_URL ="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private static Gson gson;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Also the **InterfaceApi.java** I guess the problem its here, but im not sure:

```
public interface InterfaceAPI {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @GET("login/{email}/{password}")
    Call<Usuario> login(
            @Path("email") String email,
            @Path("password") String password
    );
}
```

Also at the **LoginActivity.java** :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterfaceAPI apiInterface;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;

    private final String SALUDOS = "Hello from the other side";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Vamos a acceder a la pagina de inicio si se ha logeuado correctamente
                // a traves de este btn y mandamos datos del usuario
                userLogin();

            }
        });


    }

    private void userLogin() {
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceAPI.class);
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(checkValidaciones(email, password)){ // these are only checkings and they work
            Call<Usuario> call = apiInterface.login(email, password);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response) {
                    Usuario res = response.body();

                    if (res != null){
                        // vamos a la pagina de Inicial
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("saludo", SALUDOS);
                        //LANZAMOS
                        startActivity(intent);

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usuario correctamente logueado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        //nos quedariamos en la misma pagina de login
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error en login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {
                    //nos quedamos en la misma pagina de login
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
        }

    }

   
}
```

The application just closes when i hit the button that i catch at de loginActivity...
Can anyone help me please! Thank u in advance <3

Comment: are you getting anything in logs?

Comment: I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2004 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
W/xample.covidra: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10154; state: ENABLED

Comment: these are the console logs when im introducing the data from the activity_login ..and when i hit the login button

Comment: can you try removing     @FormUrlEncoded
from the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you add @FromUrlEncoded to the top of @GET, you will have
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FormUrlEncoded can only be
> specified on HTTP methods with request body (e.g., @POST).

Try removing @FormUrlEncoded from the method

Check if you have INTERNET permission in the manifest
Try after adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in application tag inside Manifest

Comment: Ty! yes i removed it, now it doesnt crash the app, but, still not making the connection with the back.

Comment: add that HttpLoggingInterceptor  from other answer you will get more details from Logs

Comment: YES! it was that! i guess im not very familiar with android and i miss that permission!! ty

Comment: That's very common mistake in Android development.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1'
```

Create a Retrofit object like the following:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://backend.example.com")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

add this HttpLoggingInterceptor  to get more idea about your request in Logs

Comment: TY!! very useful: the error its this : Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://1xx.xx.xx.xxx8080/login/fatima@ucm.es/12345678
    --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to 1xx.xx.xxx not permitted by network security policy
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10154; state: ENABLED

Comment: by adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest Application Tag